# PendingIntent not working with FCM notification

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent, notificationmanager

i want to open Detail activity on notification click event.
Here is the `PendingIntent` and `Notification` set class. I added `addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)` also added `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`. I searched all topics on site i found this solutions i tried all of them.

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";
    /**
     * Called when message is received.
     *
     * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
     */
    // [START receive_message]
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
        // If the application is in the foreground handle both data and notification messages here.
        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        ArrayList<String> notificationData = new ArrayList<String >(remoteMessage.getData().values());
        String fortuneID = notificationData.get(0);
        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(),fortuneID);
    }
    // [END receive_message]

    /**
     * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
     *
     * @param messageBody FCM message body received.
     */
    private void sendNotification(String messageBody,String notificationID) {

        Intent configureIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FalDetayActivity.class);
        configureIntent.putExtra("extra", "123123");
        configureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        configureIntent.setAction("dummy_unique_action_identifyer" + "123123");
        int dummyuniqueInt = new Random().nextInt(543254);
        PendingIntent pendingClearScreenIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), dummyuniqueInt, configureIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("myApp")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingClearScreenIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(1 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Here is the `getBundle` part `MainActivity`

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String quote = getIntent().getStringExtra("extra");

        ...
}
```

Another problem i want to open `FalDetailActivity` but always open `MainActiviy` and `getIntent()` always return null. Probably, my `PendingIntent` not set i did not found error please check this code. Thanks...

**UPDATE**

I update `getBroadcast` to `getActivity` and remove something

```
        Intent configureIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FalDetayActivity.class);
        configureIntent.putExtra("extra", "123123");
        configureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingClearScreenIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, configureIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: **configureIntent.setAction("dummy_unique_action_identifyer" + "123123");**
 try to remove this line and the try.

Comment: I removed still not work

Comment: instead of using **PendingIntent.getBroadcast()**
use **PendingIntent.getActivity()**

Comment: Check question update already changed still not work @RajatGupta

Comment: contentIntent
The intent to execute when the expanded status entry is clicked. If this is an activity, it must include the **FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK** flag 
Try to add this flag

Comment: Yes now work if app is running but if app is running on background still do nothing @RajatGupta

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117045/discussion-between-rajat-gupta-and-gokhancokkececi).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally i found the solution : 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/android/console-audience

When your app is in the background, Android directs notification messages to the system tray. A user tap on the notification opens the app launcher by default.

This includes messages that contain both notification and data payload. In these cases, the notification is delivered to the device's system tray, and the data payload is delivered in the extras of the intent of your launcher Activity.

Comment: can you tell me what is the code behind data payload? can you tell me whole code?  onMessageRecive method not called when app in background then how can you get data payload in which class? what is the code? Please tell me ..

Comment: Glad you've found a solution, but where do you receive the data in the launcher activity? I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: @jobbert in your main activity, use getIntent() to receive the fcm data

Answer (score 0):

You want to launch an activity with your pending intent, not send a broadcast.
Change `PendingIntent.getBroadcast(...)` to `PendingIntent.getActivity(...)`.

Instead of using `getApplicationContext()`, try to use the service's context, i.e. replace `getApplicationContext()` with `this`.

Since you are launching an activity from a service's context, you also need to add the new task intent flag -

```
configureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Also, use these flags for your pending intent -

```
PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
```